# Rename route url connection: null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

```
Route::resource('blenchs', 'BlenchController');
```

**BlenchController.php**

```
public function edit(TMblench $blench)
{
  dd($blench);
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('blench_edit'), 403);

    return view('admin.blench.edit', compact('blench'));
}
```

> result: #connection: "mysql"

But when I rename the route

```
Route::resource('blenchsssssssss', 'BlenchController');
```

**BlenchController.php**

```
public function edit(TMblench $blench)
{
  dd($blench);
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('blench_edit'), 403);

    return view('admin.blench.edit', compact('blench'));
}
```

> result: #connection: null

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Route::resource(), the name has to match model name i.e If model name is `User`, you specify `Route::resource('users', 'UserController')`.

So, `Route::resource('blenchs', 'BlenchController');` generates the following endpoints:

- GET `/photos`
- GET `/photos/create`
- POST `/photos`
- GET `/photos/{photo}`
- GET `/photos/{photo}/edit`
- PUT/PATCH `/photos/{photo}`
- DELETE `/photos/{photo}`

which injects the model `Photo` in your controller method accessible with `$photo`.

`Route::resource('blenchsssssssss', 'BlenchController');` will however generate routes with `{blenchssssssssss}` and Laravel will be looking for a model with name `Blenchsssssssss` which doesn't exist.